# What does Chunk'd tots mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw the expression in the American television food show. The menu is Chunk'd tots(Korean beef + potato tots). I know tots is a kind of fried potato but what is chunk'd means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full dish title is Kalbi Chunk'd tots. Effectively Korean beef with potato nuggets.

So, Kalbi is the meat and tot is potato. So where does Chunk'd come from?

Chunk is a noun:

> *Etymology: apparently a modification of chuck n.1 especially common in U.S.*
>
> **colloq. and dial.**
>
> a. A thick, more or less cuboidal, lump, cut off anything; e.g. wood, bread, cheese, meat, etc.

*Verbing* (And yes, I had to confirm that verbing is a real word - it's in the OED) is a process of *derivation*, often colloquial or idiomatic, of making a new verb from another word. So, *to chunk* would be to make chunks from something.

The past participle of chunk would be chunked or chunk'd - the apostrophe serves no practical purpose today, it's a stylistic device.

I can't blame the chef - Kalbi chunk'd tots sounds a lot better than Korean beef with potato nuggets